# How do I autosize an inline-block to fit its multilined text?

Tags: html, css

How can I make my inline-block autosize its fit to its multilined content?
Check my fiddle and see how the multiline text wrecks the padding.

https://jsfiddle.net/mL630u4f/1/

```css
.block {
  display: block;
  background-color: pink;
  width: 300px;
  height: 120px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.btn-holder {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  @extend .label-text;
  background: none;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 1em;
  color: blue;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="block">
  <div class="btn-holder">
    <span class="btn">lorem, ipsum &amp; dolor</span>
  </div>
</a>

<a href="#" class="block">
  <span class="btn-holder">
        <span class="btn">loremipsum, loremipsumdolor &amp; loremipsumdolor</span>
  </span>
</a>
```

Comment: Oh ok sorry. The width of the blue button is as big as its container. It doesn't shrink to its content. The left and right padding is gone.

Comment: This is working exactly as it should be.  What do you want it to look like?

Comment: The multilined version pushes the width of the blue border to the full width of the pink container. I would like to have it have the width of the content + 2x 1rem padding. (Like the singleline version)

Answer (score 0):

Just add `word-break` element to your class `.btn`
Reason for extra spacing :- The word was too big to fit in the first line's spacing and thus went in for the next line. 
For more info :- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break

```
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  @extend .label-text;
  background: none;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 1em;
  color: blue;
  text-align: center;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

Comment: word-break doesn't quite fix it. It just breaks the word in half. https://jsfiddle.net/mL630u4f/3/

Comment: @albert105 The behavior you are inquisitive about is due to the fact that the words are too big to fit in and thus go into the next line. If you have smaller words you will see the difference.

Comment: I understand where the behavior comes from. It just bugs me that I can't find a simple solution to get it the way I like.. (without using javascript)

Comment: @albert105 nothings comes off easy. That's why there are rookies and there are experts ;)